# How to get Offset from a Time Zone of a country which uses different time zone like EEST and EET

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

I want to get the offset of a time zone from a country where a device is in. Let's take an example of a device which is in Finland, Finland is currently using EEST, but for some reason my device has stored the
time zone as EET. Now we know EEST and EET have different offset's (+3 and +2 respectively). So I want a java code which will give me the correct offset by taking the time zone in EET, determining if the current time zone used in this country is actually EET or EEST (or determine if DST is active or no), and returning me the correct offset.

Note: EEST and EET is just an example I have used, I would like the code to work with any country which uses more than one Time zone at different time of the year.

I cannot use Continent/city format since the Only information I have from the device is EET timezone.

Comment: That's not how the standard java libraries work (they'd be in zone Europe/Helsinki, and know what the offset is by checking the date). There simply isn't such a thing as 'EET'. Perhaps you are reading in stamps from a system that does use obsolete 3/4-letter codes, or you're using obsolete java libraries such as `java.util.Date`. Edit the question and include your inputs and/or your code, probably both.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, [EET](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time) is _Eastern European Time_, UTC+2.

Comment: What parameter would be used to determine if the returned value of _EET_ vs. _EEST_ is valid?  The JVM will return whichever time-zone the system is using.  How would you know when to deviate?  You're saying you will already know what country the device is in?

Comment: @Reilas, The device that is giving me the value has stored the time Zone as EET, which is wrong, it should've been EEST, I will not know the country of the device, the only information I have is time Zone is EET in device.

Comment: Obviously this is an excellent illustration of why you shouldn't use the deprecated time zone acronyms (e.g. use `Europe/Helsinki` as mentioned), but why would your stored timezone be distinct from the default timezone of the VM on which it's run?

Comment: @Reilas There isn't such a thing as EET __in the java.time timezone system__ - these codes are obsolete (they neither cover reality nor are they unique) - timezone identifiers as used by java.time use `Europe/Helsinki`. You should read the `java.time` javadoc, probably :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot, so I don't understand your comment.  You are re-iterating what the question is?  He states that he wants to get the UTC offset for _EET_.

Comment: @UllaBritta, have you reviewed the [TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html) class?  It might have the procedures you're looking for.

Comment: That won't suffice. Given a time zone abbreviation, say, CST, it often has multiple interpretations, that is, may refer to several time zones on different sides of the planet. Even if you can narrow EET down to mean Eastern European Time, many countries use that. They don't all use summer time, and not in the same years and don't change to summer time on the same date. What you are asking is way outside the possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

> determine if DST is active or no

```
ZoneId
.of( "Europe/Helsinki" ) 
.getRules()
.isDaylightSavings(
    Instant.now()
)
```

## Details

EEST and EET are *not* time zones. They merely give an ambiguous hint as to what time zone might be intended, with an indication of whether Daylight Saving Time (DST) is in effect. These pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique/distinct. These should be used only when localizing for presentation to a user. These should never be used for data storage, data exchange, or business logic.

You said:

> Now we know EEST and EET have different offset's (+3 and +2 respectively)

No, we do *not* know that. There is no official/standard definition for the offsets implied by EEST and EET. The time zones implied by EEST and EET may have different offsets on some dates as their politicians may start/stop DST on different dates. Or the politicians may introduce other anomalies beside DST; politicians are unpredictable.

You said:

> I want to get the offset of a time zone from a country where a device is in.

As for determining time zone by location, that is presumptuous. The only time zone that matters for presentation is the user’s expected/desired time zone. You can *guess* what that might be. But where critical, you must confirm with the user explicitly.

You said:

> `Calendar calendar = …`

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

You said:

> determining if the current time zone used in this country is actually EET or EEST (or determine if DST is active or no)

First, determine a real time zone. Real time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region`. For example, `Africa/Casablanca` or `Pacific/Auckland`. For Finland, the only time zone is `Europe/Helsinki`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Helsinki" ) ;
```

Get the rules defined for that zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Interrogate the rules for that moment, asking if DST is in effect.

```
boolean isDST = rules.isDaylightSavings( now ) ;
```

You said:

> I cannot use Continent/city format since the Only information I have from the device is EET timezone.

Then you have incomplete information, and your task is impossible.

This is like asking for the current money exchange rate for “dollar” but you don’t know if that is the Australia dollar, the Canada dollar, the Hong Kong dollar, or the United States dollar.

Answer (score -3):

Here is tutorial in reference to TimeZone offsets.
[Time Zone and Offset Classes (The Java™ Tutorials > Date Time > Standard Calendar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html).

As an alternative to get the UTC offset you can use the *[TimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html)* class.
To create a new *TimeZone* object, you can use the *[getTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String))* method.

For this example, I'll use *EET*, or *Eastern European Time*.

```java
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET");
```

The *TimeZone* class offers the *[getOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset(long))* method, which takes either a set of values, or a [Unix-epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) timestamp as a parameter.
We can use a *[Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html)* object to obtain a time value for the *UTC*, and a timestamp using the *[getTimeInMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis())* method.

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
long offset = timeZone.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

If we printed the *offset* we'd get the following.

```
10800000
```

Which is equivalent to *3 hours*, or 3 × 60 × 60 × 1000.

In terms of *DST*, or *Daylight Saving Time*, you can utilize the following methods:  [useDaylightTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#useDaylightTime()), and [getDSTSavings](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDSTSavings()),

The first method will return *true* if the time-zone observes daylight savings, while the latter will return a value in milliseconds to be negated from the UTC offset.

Daylight Saving Time occurs at different times for different areas.

You can use a *[Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html)* object, obtainable via a *Calendar* object, to query whether the timestamp is currently observing DST or not.

```java
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
boolean dst = timeZone.inDaylightTime(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: The link you provide tells us to use the `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` classes. Yet in your code you are using the poorly designed and long outdated `TimeZone` and `Calendar` classes. That's bad idea.

Comment: @OleV.V., yes, as an alternative.  Where does the design flaw come-into-play with the task?  Additionally, how can code be considered _"long outdated"_?  It's a math equation.

Comment: @OleV.V., from the tutorial, paraphrased, _"... the Calendar class was not type safe."_, _"because the classes were mutable, they could not be used in multithreaded applications."_, and _"bugs in application code were common due to the unusual numbering of months and the lack of type safety"_.  Those factors aren't very limiting here.

Comment: @OleV.V., you should read the tutorial.

Comment: (1) It's always better to get into the habit of using the modern classes and forgetting about the old ones from the outset. (2) For many abbreviations `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` will fail to interpret it and will incorrectly give you GMT. (3) `TimeZone` has got a confusing array of DST related methods. I can't understand how they work and I suspect that some of them are flawed.

Comment: Funny, I was thinking that you should read the tutorial. And follow it.

Comment: @OleV.V., a good habit?  How about this, read a book.  Try a topic on metaphysics.  You need to consider what is called _context_.  And, I don't recommend teaching someone a habit.